# Changing Windows text size moves display items

Tags: c++, windows

My C++ Windows program positions some of the display items using the resource file and some of them programmatically.
When I change the Windows text size using Settings, it moves the programmatic items out of position.

How can I find this setting and compensate for it?

Comment: You are talking about changes made to the DPI. I started to write an answer, but this is a ***huge topic***, and there's just no way I can summarize it in a few hundred words. I can give you the simple, direct answer to your question of how you find out what the DPI is (get a DC for the screen, call `GetDeviceCaps()` with the `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` options to get the horizontal and vertical DPI settings, respectively), but that doesn't really help you much. You need to know what to do with that data. Complicated enough with a window, but dialogs in resource files use DLUs

Comment: ...for positioning, the interaction of which with DPI is [a whole other topic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/145994) in itself. Start reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx. Meanwhile, closing this question as "too broad." Come back if you have a more specific problem, or something specific that you don't understand.